# Mandatory drop down problems

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've got a form that has several mandatory fields, all of which work except the drop-down.

I'm using this code to check the fields:

```
function formCheck(formobj){
    // Enter name of mandatory fields
    var fieldRequired = Array("name", "country", "email", "tel");
    // Enter field description to appear in the dialog box
    var fieldDescription = Array("Name", "Country", "Email", "Telephone");
    // dialog message
    var alertMsg = "Please complete the following fields:\n";

    var l_Msg = alertMsg.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < fieldRequired.length; i++){
        var obj = formobj.elements[fieldRequired[i]];
        if (obj){
            switch(obj.type){
            case "select-one":
                if (obj.selectedIndex == -1 || obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text == ""){
                    alertMsg += " - " + fieldDescription[i] + "\n";
                }
                break;
            case "select-multiple":
                if (obj.selectedIndex == -1){
                    alertMsg += " - " + fieldDescription[i] + "\n";
                }
                break;
            case "text":
            case "textarea":
                if (obj.value == "" || obj.value == null){
                    alertMsg += " - " + fieldDescription[i] + "\n";
                }
                break;
            default:
            }
            if (obj.type == undefined){
                var blnchecked = false;
                for (var j = 0; j < obj.length; j++){
                    if (obj[j].checked){
                        blnchecked = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!blnchecked){
                    alertMsg += " - " + fieldDescription[i] + "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (alertMsg.length == l_Msg){
        return true;
    }else{
        alert(alertMsg);
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the code I'm using for the drop down:

```
<select name="country" id="country">
                        <option value="" disabled="disabled">Please select your country</option>
                        <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                        <option value="United States">United States</option>
...
```

What am I missing to make the user select a country rather than them leaving it on "Please select your country" and it returning nothing?

Comment: Rather than reinvent the wheel, I suggest you use a javascript library like jQuery. You'll get reliable, robust code that handles cross-browser differences.

Comment: @RedFilter: Not to mention that entire code block could be reduced to maybe 10 LLOC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example this code will always result to true:

```
obj.selectedIndex == -1 || obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text == ""
```

Both will evaluate to true. Try changing it to:

```
obj.selectedIndex == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The selectedIndex property in HTML starts at 0. (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp)

That means that it will never be -1 as you're expecting.

You have to compare it to the index 0 or better yet, compare the value and if it is an empty string then show the error message.

Right now you're comparing the text property, not the value property of the option.

Answer (score 0):

This line may be the culprit:

```
if (obj.selectedIndex == -1 || obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text == "") ...
```

It first checks if the selected index is -1, or that the selected item's `text` is empty. You will always have `text` on any selected item, assuming you're treating the "Please select ..." as the default. That option has an empty `value`, not `text` property. So I think you're comparing against the wrong property. Also, the first element's index is 0, so the index comparison is incorrect.

Try changing it to:

```
if (obj.selectedIndex < 1 || obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value == "") ...
```

Comment: It still didn't show a value or flag up the mandatory message.

Answer (score 0):

If the first item of a SELECT is **disabled** the selectedIndex will equal the first non-disabled option, not -1 as expected.